How can I fix webm in this scenario in safari?
enter image description here
I need to make my webm video to run in safari(in chrome everything is fine) but I have issues like: white background, controls, weird behaviour, I have more webm videos that works perfectly with safari
<div className="SecondPage">
<img src='200_d.gif' className='glist'/>
                <video className='video-player' autoPlay playsInline>
                    <source src='title.webm' type='video/webm' />
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
                <a className='asd1' href={dex}><img src='coin1.svg' /></a>
                <a href={pump} className='asd2'>  <img src='coin2.svg' /></a>
                <a href={tg} className='asd3'>  <img src='coin3.svg' /></a>
</div>

I have tried lots of params but nothing helped

(1) It's not clear in your picture which thing is title.webm and which thing is 200_d.gif etc. (2) No example of how it should look like when it is working properly.... (3) Is it possible that you are using a webm with transparency effects? if yes, then that will not work on Safari. You need to encode a second version now using the HEVC codec (as put inside MP4 file) because Safari does not use the competition's VP9 codecs (as put inside webM file)...
